# Rotating between images that are dynamicaly loaded from local disk using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web application that will reside on a kiosk with a folder of images that will periodically be downloaded from a server. I'm having trouble getting the application to load groups of images off the local disk and loop through them. If there is a way to do this in JavaScript, I would prefer it.

If you have any ideas on how or sample code to get started, I would appreciate the help.

I'm not a web developer so my JavaScript isn't great, code comments and descriptions are appreciated also.

Comment: Is the kiosk running a web server, or is the web application pointed at a remote site?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: The kiosk will be running a web server. So far I'm using  the JQuery cycle plugin to rotate images that aren't dynamically loaded and I'm sending a JSON object from the code behind page with file paths of images. The plugin wont work with the dynamically loaded images.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, from a web browser, is prevented from accessing local drives for security reasons. Your could, however, setup a webserver on the local machine to serve those images, and then load them via Javascript from the webserver.

For example, using jQuery:

```
$.load('http://localhost/image.jpg', function() {
    // do what you need to do with the image
});
```